# How to get the browser to detect a hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/). I can get my links to add the hashchange to the URL, but I cannot get the browser to identify hashes in the link.

The browser simply loads

`localhost:3000/pages#?type=1` as `localhost:3000/pages`

Ignoring the entire hash part.

The JS is as follows...

```
$(function(){

  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;

    $('.links a').each(function(){
      var that = $(this);
      that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
    });
  })

  $(window).hashchange();

});
```

Clearly I am missing something out here, though this code is essentially what is provided in the demo on the plugin docs.

Comment: I don't get it? Why would you need a plugin, as this is supported out of the box in newer versions of jQuery, and why would you need to check all the links against the hash to assing a selected class when a hashchange does'nt reload the page, and you could just assign the class directly!

Comment: The links which use this code reload different content into a div on the page using a .load function. I need people to be able to use the back and forward browser buttons, thus cycling through the div content as it changes. As well as enabling users to copy and paste the URLs to people, which load the correct content in the div.

Comment: This isn't really so much about adding the selected class as it is getting the browser to recognise hash links as url parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.hash` is the way to get the string of the hash. From there, manipulate the string as you need.